# Clicking team tags from the front page redirects to main site tags instead of team tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

On the front page, tags in the team box redirects to the main-site tag instead of the team equivalent.

> [image]

This applies to all the tags (the rest are hidden because I'm not sure if I'm allowed to share it or not). All the tags redirect to `stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag>` instead of `stackoverflow.com/c/<team>/questions/tagged/<tag>` when on the SO front page. When navigating to `/c/<team>/*`, the tags appear to be correct (going to for an instance `/c/team/<team>/questions` or a question, tag feed, or a search shows the correct links at least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great catch. Fixed! Thank you for reporting.