# Teams links on the front page once again redirect to main instead of the team

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, hyperlinks

Links to "modified x hours ago" (as well as equivalent links for asked and presumably answered) redirect to main instead of the team. This is a link-based regression of [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388793/6296561). No other links (including tags) appear to be broken this time around.

> [image: Screenshot showing "asked 4 hours ago" on a team indicate the URL "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407" instead of the correct team URL]

I.e. all the URLs that are meant to redirect to `/c/<team>/questions/1234` (or possibly to an answer depending on the URL type) instead redirect to `/questions/1234`. With great similarity to the tag-based bug, it's only broken on the front page, and not on the team's question list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. These "mixed content" areas can be a tad tricky sometimes. This regression was caused by the recent changes to the summary layout. The new layout was based off of existing code that did not have the proper fix in place for this issue.